# How to add particular columns of a query to spreadsheet object in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I have a query object which contains 5 columns, but I only need to add 4 columns to the spreadsheet. When I am using `<cfset spreadSheetAddRows(spreadSheetObj,qryObj)>` it is adding all the columns to the spreadsheet. I cannot remove the 5th column from the query as it is required for some other purpose.

So How can I add only 4 columns from the query to spreadsheet?

Ex: My query contains 4 columns like "Id,Name,Roll,CGPA"

But my Excel sheet should contain only "Id,Name,Roll".

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add each row individually with `SpreadsheetAddRow(spreadsheetObj, data [,row, column, insert]);`

And for columns use `SpreadsheetAddColumn(SpreadsheetObj, data[, startRow, startColumn, insert]);`

- [SpreadsheetAddRow Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-67ad.html)
- [SpreadsheetAddColumn Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7478.html)

Comment: Just check my example exactly what i want.

Comment: Your answer is no way related to my question.

Comment: Neither of those are "great" options as they require a "comma delimited list of cell entries", requiring hacks if the data contains commas. Unfortunately, there is no one-line-solution. All of the options have drawbacks, but personally I think the others are cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Query-of-Query to create a temporary query that you can then use to pump into your `spreadSheetAddRows()`.

```
<cfquery name="local.spreadsheetQuery" dbtype="query">
SELECT Id,Name,Roll
FROM variables.originalQuery
</cfquery>
```

Then use `<cfset spreadSheetAddRows(spreadSheetObj,local.spreadsheetQuery)>` instead of `<cfset spreadSheetAddRows(spreadSheetObj,variables.originalQuery)>`.

Comment: There is no direct function to do this?

Comment: This isn't a very good way to accomplish the task. There is no need for a second query.

Comment: *There is no direct function to do this?* No. The options are a) Loop and add the cell values manually b) create an intermediary query containing only the columns needed OR c) add all columns, then [delete the extra(s)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-660681012216ab44a6-7fff.html). Each option has pros and cons.

Comment: Actually, it's potentially a very efficient way to accomplish the task.  Once you do the q of q, it's a simple <cfspreadsheet query="newquery">

Comment: I stand corrected. I was always under the impression that the QoQ would slow the process down, depending on the size of the spreadsheet.

Comment: In terms of what happens under the hood, it's probably less efficient.  The q of q has to execute and the results take up more memory.  However, the increased simplicity of the code might make it worthwhile.